# how auto Replace Scr if url with .jpg,.png & .js use js script

Tags: javascript, replace

how auto Replace Scr if url with .jpg,.png & .js 
for Ex
in my home page have some image link 
`<img src="http://www.lx5.in/img/img.png"/>` its auto convert to `<img src="http://www.lx5.in.cdn.com/img/img.png"/>`
is it possible use any .js script ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible; have you tried anything at all, yet? And you want to *use* 'js' or you want to change the `src` *if* it contains the file-type 'js'?

Comment: i just defined a .js in header who replay the .png .jpg and .js URL.
can you tell me the full js code i don't have any idea about js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively simple approach to your problem:

```
function changeSrc (img) {
    // the file types you indicate you wanted to base the action upon:
    var fileTypes = ['png','jpg'],
        // gets the 'src' property from the current 'img' element:
        src = img.src,
        /* finds the extension, by splitting the 'src' by '/' characters,
           taking the last element, splitting that last string on the '.' character
           and taking the last element of that resulting array:
        */
        ext = src.split('/').pop().split('.').pop();
    // if that 'ext' variable exists (is not undefined/null):
    if (ext) {
        // iterates over the entries in the 'fileTypes' array:
        for (var i = 0, len = fileTypes.length; i < len; i++){
            /* if the 'ext' is exactly equal (be aware of capitalisation)
               to the current entry from the 'fileTypes' array:
            */
            if (ext === fileTypes[i]) {
                // finds the '.in/' string, replaces that with '.in.cdn.com/':
                img.src = src.replace(/.in\//,'.in.cdn.com/');
            }
        }
    }

}

// gets all the 'img' elements from the document:
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// iterates over all those images:
for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++){
    // calls the function, supplying the 'img' element:
    changeSrc(images[i]);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pruNB/1/).

References:

- [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: img.src = src.replace(/.in\//,'.in.cdn.com/'); its replace any top level domain to top level.cdn.com or only one select domain like lx5.in ? i need to defined for  replace ? can is it possible to gate image SCR and add .cdn.com after the top level domain ??? thanks for all

Comment: Of course it's possible, but it would be much easier to answer your question if you could clarify your question, and explicitly state your requirements, rather than iterating the answer in response to updates. So, please, look at your question and take the time to edit it to clearly reflect what you need. And, as it's currently written, this explicitly works with only the `.in` tld, because that's what was in your question.

Comment: img.src = src.replace(/.com\//,'.com.cdn.com/'); here .com to .com.cdn.com ya ok can i replace with / like img.src = src.replace(//\//,'.cdn.com//'); here replace / to .cdn.com/ only 1 / after top level domain . is it possible how to write it ?
Dear David Thomas Thanks for spend your tome for Answer. really thanks nice i love it its work but can its work for all tld ? what i say above these way or outre ? . Thanks best Answer <3